# Improving Dropzone.js upload speed for web app

Tags: asp.net, gallery, dropzone.js, dropzone

I am using dropzone for a photo gallery application built using dot net core. We use dropzone for uploading of many photos from user PC to the cloud / web app. These photos are ranging from 10 MBs to 60 MBs size each and are uploaded in an album of 3000-4000 photos each.

The problem we face is the upload speed.

We are using a 100 mbps broadband connection, isolated just for testing, so there is no other network traffic, no other sites or operations performed at the same time. The internet download / upload test gives speed of about 93-94 Mbps.

[image]

We uploaded about 430 photos taking up total of 1900 MBs apx space. The parallel upload is set to 2 photos for now. The time taken with dropzone was about 3 Hour 52 Min. The same file uploaded on GDrive Web in about 31 minutes. That's a huge difference. We used Gdrive just to benchmark upload speed here.

What could be wrong and how we can improve this?

Comment: Wild guess, but:
- GDrive must have tweaked their TCP layer and increased the standard 64kb limit, which reduces the needed amount of packets
- GDrive must have a server closer to you than your test server, which reduces ping (which is weighing down every packet)
- GDrive must be allowing more parallel uploads than you do
With all that in mind, multiply everything together, and you get a way faster upload speed thanks to a fully tweaked app+server :)

Comment: How do we do to support more parallel uploads